# Redirect only a single folder to a new website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect an old part of my website to a new website. This part is contained in a folder, `http://example.com/infos/`.

All pages or subfolders should be redirected to the homepage of the new website,
`http://www.new-website.com/`

e.g.

- `http://example.com/infos/` redirects to `http://www.new-website.com`
- `http://example.com/infos/test.html` redirects to `http://www.new-website.com`
- `http://example.com/infos/sub/hello.html` redirects to `http://www.new-website.com`

However I don't want to redirect

- `http://example.com/`
- `http://example.com/geo.html`
- `http://example.com/test/1.html`

I tried the following declaration on a .htaccess file, but it didn't work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^infos/(.*)$ http://www.new-web-site.com [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? Does rewriting work at all? Was the rewriting done, but to a wrong target? Did nothing happen? Do you get any errors in the log files? Does the universe implode? _Be precise!_

Comment: Where did you put this .htaccess file?

Comment: If your .htaccess file is in the "/infos" subdirectory then you should remove `infos/` from your `RewriteRule` pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

This one depends on who you are using to host your website. There might be a redirects button that takes you to a page to add a redirect. You could redirect the whole site (e.g. anything starting with `http://example.com/`) or just certain folders on the site.

**Option 2**

Place a file called `.htaccess` in `http://example.com/`(root folder) with the following contents:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/my_redirected_folder/ http://www.new-website.com/
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply. My mistake that I wasn't placing the .htaccess in the root. I tried Option 2 and works perfect

Comment: You can put a .htaccess in other folders. You would probably just put ^/ if you put the .htaccess in your /infos folder